# [jquery] увеличение уеньшение картинки по таймеру

Tags: jquery

Интересует данный вопрос, при наведении на картинку должно увеличить и уменьшить плавно и опять по новой как бы моргания такое. в какую сторону копать?

Более правильный наверное вопрос будет в какую сторону копать при увеличении из центра картинки что бы она была зацентрирована.

Answer (score 1):

Увеличивай и уменьшай картинку с помощью **animate** и вместе с этим анимируй ее отступы влево и вверх..

вот как-то так:

```
$('#img').animate({
  'width': '320px',
  'marginLeft': '-60px',
  'marginTop': '-60px',
}, 1000 )
```

Для пульсации нужно использовать callback функцию:

как только картинка увеличилась, запускается функция, которая ее уменьшает и по кругу. 
А чтобы прекратить все это безобразие (пульсацию всмысле), при потере курсора мыши это все останавливаешь.

Но я думаю писать это самому мало смысла, полюбому уже есть готовые примеры.

Comment: готовых вариантов не нашел, гуглил уже.